# Background not covering site on one page

Tags: css, background-color

I am working on this page: http://www.myfortune3cart.com/journeyfilm/cartadd.cgi

The background below the horizontal navigation is not continuing down to the footer. It does work on other pages:
http://www.myfortune3cart.com/journeyfilm/Products.html

I can't find where to change the css.

Screen shot:
[image]

Thank you,

Matt

Comment: the two pages look the same to me background wise... can you post a screenshot and point out what you mean?

Comment: It's not possible to set both columns the same height using CSS only. You can only simulate that for desktop screen (because you have fixed width there) using `background-image` with both black-columns on  `.home-content`.

Comment: I added the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

What happening is on your Product page your background extends to the footer because there is content that fills the container. On your home page the background image does not do this because you dont have enough content to allow the container to extend to your footer.

So once you add your content to the home page the container will grow closer to the footer if there is enough content. If that is not good enough you can add a min-height to your content container so it always touches your footer. I added a `min-height: 800px;` to your `.page-right-container` and your content will show like you intended. You will have to adjust the number to fit exactly the way you want but that should get you started.

Comment: I tried this and it still shows the background is not extending. Now any product page gets too long due to the change: http://www.myfortune3cart.com/journeyfilm/Products-The_Runner_-_Soundtrack.html. It is the cart with products in it that is the problem.

Comment: I'm looking at your website now and noticed that in the .page-right-container container you have the min-height set to around 500. If you increase that count to 759px the background will reach the elements below it.

Comment: As I said, that will extend the product page... if you look at any product and do this it will have a large empty gray area below it. Also, if I have 10 products in the cart it will continue to do the same thing as now. There should be a way to make it expand based on content.