# Extend Div Height According to Content

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on this site: http://www.myfortune3cart.com/journeyfilm/content.cgi

My problem is that when I shrink the screen for the mobile site the gray box behind the footer does not extend to the bottom of the boxes in the footer. Here is a screen shot:[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area clear" role="complementary">
        <div class="sidebar-one ftr-sidebar">
        <aside id="egw-2" class="widget widget_egw"><div style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border:3px solid #ffffff;" class="egw-widget  box">
    <img src="http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/JF_website_nav_bottom_watch_01.jpg" style="width:100%; height=100%" alt="WATCH" title="WATCH" class="zoom_in"><a style="padding:10px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) ; color:#ffffff; font-size:13px;" class="mask fadein" href="http://journeyfilm.com/watch"><h2 style=" color: #c5c5c3;font-size:16px;">WATCH</h2>
            </a></div>
</aside>        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-two ftr-sidebar">
        <aside id="egw-3" class="widget widget_egw"><div style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border:3px solid #ffffff;" class="egw-widget  box">
    <img src="http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/JF_website_nav_bottom_buy_01.jpg" style="width:100%; height=100%" alt="BUY" title="BUY" class="zoom_in"><a style="padding:10px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) ; color:#ffffff; font-size:13px;" class="mask fadein" href="http://store.journeyfilm.com/"><h2 style=" color: #c5c5c3;font-size:16px;">BUY</h2>
            </a></div>
</aside>        </div>
                <div class="sidebar-three ftr-sidebar">
        <aside id="egw-4" class="widget widget_egw"><div style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border:3px solid #ffffff;" class="egw-widget  box">
    <img src="http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/JF_website_nav_bottom_read_01.jpg" style="width:100%; height=100%" alt="READ" title="READ" class="zoom_in"><a style="padding:10px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) ; color:#ffffff; font-size:13px;" class="mask fadein" href="http://journeyfilm.com/read"><h2 style=" color: #c5c5c3;font-size:16px;">READ</h2>
            </a></div>
</aside>        </div>
                <div class="sidebar-four ftr-sidebar">
        <aside id="egw-5" class="widget widget_egw"><div style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border:3px solid #ffffff;" class="egw-widget  box">
    <img src="http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/JF_website_nav_bottom_hire_01.jpg" style="width:100%; height=100%" alt="HIRE" title="HIRE" class="zoom_in"><a style="padding:10px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) ; color:#ffffff; font-size:13px;" class="mask fadein" href="http://journeyfilm.com/hire"><h2 style=" color: #c5c5c3;font-size:16px;">HIRE</h2>
            </a></div>
</aside>        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#secondary {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.85) !important;
    /*height: 100%; - I added this but it pushes the box way too far down. Also tried 'auto'*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1250px;
    min-height: 161px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How's this question different from your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054548/background-not-covering-site-on-one-page)?

Comment: It is different because the other question was dealing with the background of the body on only the cart page. This is dealing with the responsiveness of the footer on every page. It is obvious from the answers that this is a different problem. Even the screenshots are of different areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div `<div role="complementary" class="widget-area clear" id="secondary">` needs to have the `<div class="clear"></div>` at the bottom (but within it). You have one outside of it but if you were to place one inside it, it should solve your problem.

The reason why it needs to have the div with the clear is because the items within your div `<div role="complementary" class="widget-area clear" id="secondary">` are all floating.

---

I do want to say that I don't support your floated elements because the proper way would have been to set them as inline-blocks, but that's a different story.

Comment: This worked. I also removed the padding per MacInnes but it didn't fix the problem completely. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's this line that's the problem:

```
.footer-content { width:100%; max-width:1280px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px 0px 151px; }
```

You've got bottom padding of 151px. Take that out and it looks good to me.